# Why am I getting an "undefined setting" for proj/test:executeTests with the new <task>.all(<scope filter>) API?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use the new scope filtering API on tasks to execute all tests for a project and it's dependencies.

```
val select = ScopeFilter(inDependencies(p), inConfigurations(Test))
val agg = executeTests.all(select).map(aggregateTestOutput)
executeTests in Test := agg.value
```

But I'm getting the error

```
[error] Runtime reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   proj/test:executeTests from proj/test:executeTests
```

With `ScopeFilter(inDependencies(p, includeRoot=false), inConfigurations(Test))`, it will run the tests from the projects dependencies.  I've tried even just making the scope filter `ScopeFilter(inProject(p), inConfigurations(Test))` and it fails with the same error.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a problem with the dead code elimination in the settings processor.  `all` is implemented with `flatMap`, so all of the dependencies aren't statically known.  The dead code elimination incorrectly discards the default `executeTests` because it isn't used statically.  Try explicitly referencing the previous value, like:

```
val select = ScopeFilter(inDependencies(p, includeRoot=false), inConfigurations(Test))
val agg = executeTests.all(select)

executeTests in Test := {
   val outs = (executeTests in Test).value +: agg.value
   aggregateTestOutput(outs)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, that doesn't quite work out.  Now I'm getting `[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode (state=Blocked,blockedOn=1,calledBy=0,blocking=2): {file:/home/rwallace/Development/amkt/}webapp/test:test not evaluated`.  I have never seen that before so can't yet guess what is going on.

Comment: Since the previous `executeTests` is explicitly referenced, can you try using the `includeRoot=false` variant?  In any case, definitely file a bug.

Comment: That seems to be doing the trick. But doesn't that mean the `Tests.Output` from the current project won't be included in the results? Or is there some magic I'm missing?

Comment: Yes.  I edited my answer with the full workaround.  Instead of calling `aggregateTestOutput` directly on the result of `all`, call it after prepending the explicit result.

Comment: Right, of course.  Everything is working as I wanted now.  I will raise an issue in the morning. Thanks!